# Library sharing suddenly stopped working

Tags: itunes, network, sharing, macos

I have three Macs on the same local network, all running iTunes 11 (one running 11.0, the other two running 11.1). As of today, suddenly none of the computers' libraries appear on any of the others as a shared library.

On all three computers, library sharing is enabled in iTunes preferences, Shared Libraries are set to be visible (under General), and Shared Libraries are *not* set to be hidden under Parental Controls.

Nothing with my network setup has changed, and I ran Network Diagnostics and everything is normal. None of the computers have even been rebooted!

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens to me sometimes too - quitting and relaunching iTunes usually fixes the problem.

Comment: Tried that multiple times on all the machines, to no avail.

Comment: Tried again a few hours later and now they all work. Nothing changed. Weird!